# Paste formatting from one range to another in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, format

I'm using the following code to compare two worksheets. If a record doesn't exist in the second worksheet I copy certain columns from the first worksheet to the second.

The problem I'm having is that I need the formatting on the new lines in Sheet2 to match the formatting in the rest of the worksheet. I added the code between the "New Code" comment block but I keep getting the error message: Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed.

The error is occurring on this line: ws.Range("A2:AJ").Copy

I'm using Excel 2013 if that helps.

Thanks for your help.

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub CheckData()

        Dim Lastrow, Newrow As Long
        Dim i As Long
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim rng As Range

    ' Turn off notifications
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = ws.Range("A2:AJ2")

        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Test.xlsx"
        With Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

            Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 2 To Lastrow

                If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A").Value, ws.Columns("A"), 0)) Then

                   Newrow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
                   .Cells(i, "A").Copy ws.Cells(Newrow, "A")
                   .Cells(i, "B").Copy ws.Cells(Newrow, "E")
                   .Cells(i, "C").Copy ws.Cells(Newrow, "F")
                   .Cells(i, "D").Copy ws.Cells(Newrow, "G")
                   .Cells(i, "E").Copy ws.Cells(Newrow, "H")
                   ws.Cells(Newrow, "I") = "New submission created on" & " " & .Cells(i, "L")
                   .Cells(i, "F").Copy ws.Cells(Newrow, "J")
                   .Cells(i, "G").Copy ws.Cells(Newrow, "K")
                   .Cells(i, "H").Copy ws.Cells(Newrow, "L")
                   .Cells(i, "I").Copy ws.Cells(Newrow, "M")
                   .Cells(i, "J").Copy ws.Cells(Newrow, "N")
                   ws.Cells(Newrow, "AJ") = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")

                   'New Code

                   ws.Range("A2:AJ").Copy
                   ws.Cells(Newrow, "A").PasteSpecial _
                   Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                   SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                   Application.CutCopyMode = False

                   'End New Code

                End If

            Next i

        End With

        Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Close savechanges:=False

    ' Turn on notifications
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Message Box showing that process is complete.

        MsgBox "Done!"

    End Sub
```

Comment: The row number is missing in the range being copied ws.Range("A2:AJ?").Copy..... replace ? with row number and it will work.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks.